# passing in a 2D array into a function

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, multidimensional-array

I have looked at quite a few topics on multiple websites on how to pass in an a 2D array into a function. but for some reason none of them seems to be working correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void display(char maze[NUM_COLS],int NUM_ROWS);

int findpath(int x, int y);





int main(void)

{
 int NUM_ROWS;
 int NUM_COLS;
 std::cin >> NUM_ROWS >> NUM_COLS;
 std::string w;
 char maze[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

 getline(std::cin, w);


 for (int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
 {
    for(int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
    {
        maze[row][col] = w[col + (row * NUM_COLS)];
    }
 }

 if ( find_path(0, 0) == 1 )
 {
  printf("Success!\n");
 }
 else
 {
  printf("Failed\n");
 }

  display(maze[NUM_COLS],int NUM_ROWS);


    return 0;

}


void display(char maze[NUM_COLS],int NUM_ROWS)
{

    printf("MAZE:\n");

    for ( int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++ )

        printf("%.*s\n", NUM_COLS, maze[i]);

    printf("\n");



    return;

}





int findpath(int x, int y)

{

    // If x,y is outside maze, return false.

    if ( x < 0 || x > NUM_COLS - 1 || y < 0 || y > NUM_ROWS - 1 ) 
    {
     return 0;
    }

    // If x,y is the goal, return 1.

    if ( maze[y][x] == 'G' ) 
    {
     return 1;
    }

    // If x,y is not open, return false.

    if ( maze[y][x] != ' ' && maze[y][x] != 'S' ) 
    {
     return 0;
    }


    // Mark x,y part of solution path.

    maze[y][x] = '+';

    // If find_path North of x,y is 1, return 1.

    if ( find_path(x, y - 1) == 1 ) 
    {
     return 1;
    }

    // If find_path East of x,y is 1, return 1.

    if ( find_path(x + 1, y) == 1 ) 
    {
     return 1;
    }

    // If find_path South of x,y is 1, return 1.

    if ( find_path(x, y + 1) == 1 ) 
    {
     return 1;
    {

    // If find_path West of x,y is 1, return 1.

    if ( find_path(x - 1, y) == 1 ) 
    {
     return 1;
    }

    // Unmark x,y as part of solution path.

    maze[y][x] = 'x';

    return 0;
}
```

I just cant find any way to pass in my 2D array to make everything work. the functions work if i just force a 2D array outside of main. but when getting the info and having to pass them into the function it gives me declare errors.

```
void display(char maze[NUM_COLS],int NUM_ROWS);

  display(maze[NUM_COLS],int NUM_ROWS);
```

this is my problem. when i compile, my error is that its not taking in any of the pieces of my array. i just don't know the correct way to pass in my array. the code work. if i set a 2D array globally so that i don't have to pass anything and the functions can just grab the NUM_COLS and NUM_ROWS as well as the array itself and mess with it, the functions compiles and runs.

Comment: Right now, having looked it over so far only, I see many scope/local variable shadowing, a define that must be missing, incorrect function use... I say this, because it leads me to wonder if this is the actual source you're using -- because it does not compile as is.

Comment: I'd think the first step shall be reducing the example to the bare minimum showing the problem you gave right now! Create a version which doesn't try to do anything even remotely clever with the array.

Comment: `char maze[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];` is what is known as a "variable-length array" (VLA), i.e. its dimensions are not constants known at compile time. VLAs are only supported in C99 (and then not completely by most compilers) and are not part of the C++ standard. Therefore, what you are using is a non-standard language extension.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T, size_t rows, size_t cols>
void display(T (&matrix)[rows][cols])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            std::cout << matrix[i][j];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char maze[3][4] = {
        "asd",
        "123",
        "fgh"
    };
    display<char, 3, 4>(maze);
}
```